# A 'tagged' page does not render any content for me when logged in

Tags: support, tags

When logged in, this shows no content for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock
Content flashes momentarily and disappears.

When I search, there is no problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=actionbarsherlock
This includes many that have been tagged with 'actionbarsherlock'.

Same problem in up to date Chrome & Safari on OS X 10.8.5.

Other tags work. Works when not logged in. I tried clearing browser cache & restarting.

Comment: Any ad blockers installed? JavaScript errors? When you say "other browsers", what browser are you seeing this on (version and OS details please)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all questions tagged with [actionbarsherlock](/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock) are also tagged with [android](/questions/tagged/android). In fact, there's only [140 that aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock+-android) (out of the 3,000 questions with the tag).

Looking at your user preferences, I see that you have the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag in both your favorite **and** ignored tags. You also have the "hide ignored tags" checkbox enabled. That means that every question tagged with [android](/questions/tagged/android) is going to be hidden from your view when your page finishes loading.

Comment: Thank you. Ignoring Android was definitely a mistake/slip at some point.